# query to check multiple revsions on a table

Tags: sql

Need a query to check ids with multiple revisionnums

```
id  reviionnum
1    0
2    0
1    1
3    1
2    1
```

The query should result

```
id revisionnum
3    1
```

Please help

Comment: You really need to expand on this question. You need to show that you've at least tried this yourself. Also, what platform are you on (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc)?

Comment: Add row (4, 0), and adjust the expected result!

Comment: Seems to me you're asking for ID's w/o multiple revisions.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want ids with only one revision number, you can use aggregation:

```
select id, min(revissionnum)
from t
group by id
having count(*) = 1;
```

The `min()` is the value if there is only one row.

Comment: hmm.. this works..thanks..
and if need the vice versa, I mean for all those who has multiple revisionnums?

Comment: You can get t he ids just by changing the `= 1` to `<> 1`.

Comment: When I tried to use in my query, I am getting NOT a group by expression error